# Best practice for named entity recognition on large texts

Tags: natural-language, text-mining, named-entity-recognition

What are the best practices to apply NER to large texts (*e.g* 20 pages+)?

One common advice is to split the text before passing it as input to the model. However this can require a significant manual work of establishing splitting rules, especially if there are many different templates.

What are other alternatives or complementary practices when building a NER solution for large documents?

Are there common tricks to have a generalizable approach with regards to the data splitting logic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most (if not all) existing NER data work on the sentence level, so models trained on those datasets also expect its input to be a sentence.

Sentence-splitting is part of most NLP toolkits and works remarkably well. In most cases, rule-based procedures such as in [NLTK](https://www.nltk.org/api/nltk.tokenize.html). More advanced tools use machine-learned tokenization, such as UDPipe (best used via [spacy-udpipe](https://pypi.org/project/spacy-udpipe/) wrapper) or [Stanza](https://stanfordnlp.github.io/stanza/index.html) both working for many languages.